# How to get the template Id in controller? template Id is returning NULL for the custom template in the custom module

Tags: magento2, module, email, custom, email-templates

> **Index.php**

```
<?php
    namespace Eaglerocket\Customquote\Controller\Index;
    
    use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
    use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
    use Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;
    use Magento\Framework\Filesystem;
    use Magento\Framework\App\Request\DataPersistorInterface;
    use Magento\Framework\Translate\Inline\StateInterface;
    use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;
    
    class Index extends Action
    {
        private $dataPersistor;
        protected $context;
        private $fileSystem;
        protected $_transportBuilder;
        protected $inlineTranslation;
        protected $scopeConfig;
        protected $storeManager;
    
         public function __construct(
            \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
            \Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder $transportBuilder,
            \Magento\Framework\Translate\Inline\StateInterface $inlineTranslation,
            \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
            \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
    
        ) {
            parent::__construct($context );
            $this->_context = $context;
            $this->_transportBuilder = $transportBuilder;
            $this->inlineTranslation = $inlineTranslation;
            $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
            $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
    
        }
    
        public function execute()
        {

            $post = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();
            // $filesData = $this->getRequest()->getFiles('upload_document');

            $txt='<table>';

            if($post['comment1']){
            $txt.='<tr><td><strong>Comment</strong>:'.$post['comment1'].'</td></tr>';
            }
            if($post['comment2']){
            $txt.='<tr><td><strong>Comment</strong>:'.$post['comment2'].'</td></tr>';
            }if($post['comment3']){
            $txt.='<tr><td><strong>Comment</strong>:'.$post['comment3'].'</td></tr>';
            }
            $txt.='</table>';

            $templateOptions = array('area' => \Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_FRONTEND,
            'store' => $this->storeManager->getStore()->getId()
            );
            $storeId=$this->storeManager->getStore()->getId();
            $templateVars = array(
            'store' => $this->storeManager->getStore(),
            'customer_name' => 'John Doe',
            'message'   => 'Hello Auriga!!.'
            );
            $from = array('email' => "kirti003shukla@gmail.com", 'name' => 'Name of Sender');
            $this->inlineTranslation->suspend();
            $to = array('kirti003shukla@gmail.com');

            $storeScope = \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE;
            $templateId = $this->scopeConfig->getValue ( 'eaglerocket/customquote/email_template', \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
            $storeId
            );var_dump($templateId);die;
            $transport = $this->_transportBuilder->setTemplateIdentifier($templateId, $storeScope)->setTemplateOptions($templateOptions)
            ->setTemplateVars($templateVars)
            ->setFrom($from)
            ->addTo($to)
            ->getTransport();
            $transport->sendMessage();
            $this->messageManager->addSuccess(__('Mail Sent Successfully'));
            $this->inlineTranslation->resume();
            $this->messageManager->addSuccess(__('Form successfully submitted'));
            $this->_redirect('post_requirements');
        }
    
    }
```

> **view/frontend/email/custom_email.html**

```
 <!--@Subject Email Template @-->
    <!--@vars
    {"store url=\"\"":"Store Url",
    "skin url=\"images/logo_email.gif\" _area='frontend'":"Email Logo Image"}
    @-->
    <!--@styles
    body,td { color:#2f2f2f; font:11px/1.35em Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }
    @-->
    {{template config_path="design/email/header_template"}}
    
    <p>{{trans "Hi "}} {{var customer_name}},</p>
    <p>
    {{trans "Thank You for Registering,"}}
    {{trans "We will send You Link along with the Password for you to log in. Stay connected for updates."}}
    </p>
    
    {{var store.getFrontendName()}}
    {{template config_path="design/email/footer_template"}}
```

> **system.xml**

```
   <?xml version="1.0" ?>
    <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
        <system>
            <section id="eaglerocket" showInDefault="1" showInStore="1" showInWebsite="1" sortOrder="10" translate="label">
                <label>Custom Email</label>
                <tab>general</tab>
                <resource>Eaglerocket_Customquote::config_eaglerocket_customquote</resource>
                <group id="custom" showInDefault="1" showInStore="1" showInWebsite="1" sortOrder="10" translate="label">
                    <label>Custom Email Setting</label>
                    <field id="email_template" showInDefault="1" showInStore="1" showInWebsite="1" sortOrder="10" translate="label comment" type="select">
                        <label>Custom Email Template</label>
                        <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Email\Template</source_model>
                    <comment/>
                    </field>
                </group>
            </section>
        </system>
    </config>
```

//email_templates.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../Magento/Email/etc/email_templates.xsd">
   <template id="eaglerocket_custom_email_template" label="eaglerocket_custom_email_template" file="custom_email.html" type="html" module="Eaglerocket_Customquote" area="frontend" />
</config>
```

Comment: Upload your system.xml also.

Comment: uploaded it as asked

Comment: Are you able to resolve it?

Comment: Have you created email_templates.xml file?

Comment: yes I did and updated in the code too. New error is coming 2 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\MailException): Unable to send mail: Unknown error
Exception #1 (Laminas\Mail\Transport\Exception\RuntimeException): Unable to send mail: Unknown error

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
$templateId = $this->scopeConfig->getValue ( 'eaglerocket/customquote/email_template',null);
var_dump($templateId);die;
```

Comment: invalid scope type is the exception I got

Answer (score 0):

better create one helper

```
<?php
namespace <Vendor>\<Module>\Helper;

class Data extends \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper
{
    const XML_PATH_EMAIL_TEMPLATE  = 'eaglerocket/custom/email_template';

    public function getemailTemplate(){
        $storeScope = \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE;
        return $this->scopeConfig->getValue(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_TEMPLATE,$storeScope);
    }

}
```

And then add helper dependency in your controller and then call helper function and get email template id.

Controller code like this

```
class Index implements Action
{
   
    protected $helperData;


    public function __construct(
        <Vendor>\<module>\Helper\Data $helperData
    )
    {
        $this->helperData = $helperData;
    }


    public function execute()
    {
       echo $this->helperData->getemailTemplate();
    }
}
```

Comment: NULL is printed

Comment: check updated answer